# Editing Drupal Site

Tags: php, drupal

We've inherited an old Drupal site. I have to say I've never used Drupal before in my life. We normally use Modx for that sort of thing. I've spend most of the day trying to find a section of code which needs to be updated.

I'm sure not everyone uses Drupal the exact same way and it looks like the people who originally created the site may have added in quite a bit of custom stuff.

I've found a template file in themes folder code section bellow:

```
<?php print $page_top; ?>
<?php print $page; ?>
<?php print $page_bottom; ?>
```

I need to edit something that's in $page_top.. but I've got no clue where this is.. I've search  the rest of the file tree and can't find anything. When it comes to Drupal it's self it doesn't look to be block which was my original thinking.

Comment: Can you specify which version of Drupal it is? Which file was the above found in? page.tpl.php? Ultimately those includes are found in html.tpl.php for Drupal 7 can you confirm? Can assist better after that

Comment: Looks like "page_top" is a region of your template, you can confirm it opening /sites/all/themes/your_theme/your_theme.info (where you'll find the name of this region in your admin interface, typically "Page Top"). If so, in this region are displayed blocks : on your admin toolbar : structure -> blocks you'll find what is rendered in this region (blocks, views, menus...)

Comment: Those where found in html.tpl.php. I did find the information in the end it was in the page.tpl.php. Thanks for point me in the right direction.